# Relating Two Different NSDictionaries using keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

suppose If  i have two NSDictionaries with same keys but different values. i need to find the value of the Dictionary 2 using Dictionary 1’s key.

**example**

```
MYDictionaryONE
{
58937 =     {
        Changed = NO;
        ChangedColorCode = Nil;
            };
58859 =     {
        Changed = NO;
        ChangedColorCode = Nil;

    };
}


MYDictionaryTWO
{
58937 =     {
        pass = YES;
        Fail=Nil;
            };
58859 =     {
        pass = YES;
        Fail = Nil;

    };
}
```

I just want to take one key at a time from MYDictionaryONE and search the value related to that key in MYDictionaryTWO. I tried storing all keys but i missed the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below snippet.

```
 NSArray *allKeys = [MYDictionaryONE allKeys];

    for(int i = 0; i < allKeys.count; i++)
    {
          NSString *key = allKeys[i];
          id object = MYDictionaryTWO[key];

    }
```